# Kotlin lambda / Java SAM interop - type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I have an existing Java interface defined as follows

```
public interface MyRetriever extends Function<String, Optional<String>> {}
```

and want to define a variable holding a Kotlin lambda which conforms to the SAM conversion as per my understanding

```
var a : MyRetriever = { s : String -> Optional.ofNullable(s.toLowerCase()) }
```

But instead I get a type mismatch error.

```
Type missmatch.
Required: MyRetriever
Found: (String) -> Optional<String>
```

The lambda actually matches the Java function definition, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a SAM conversion, you need to explicitly provide a type:

```
var a = MyRetriever { s : String -> Optional.ofNullable(s.toLowerCase()) }
```

Note that you may omit declaration of type for `a` the way you did it before.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why? I mean, my expectation was that I would not have since the type matches. And Kotlin is so good at guessing things like this

Comment: @Xipo I think this is because Kotlin cannot correctly convert it's internal function type to SAM-converted lambda, so when you declared it as `var a: MyRetriever`, there was a type mismatch. See [this blogpost](https://readyset.build/kotlins-sam-problem-f315ffe6be3a) for more information.